# Find all repositories that point to mine as an external

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repository containing a library, and many other repositories with projects that include that library as an external. Is there a way to list all the places where my library repository (or folder in that repository) is referenced as an external?

Comment: I don't think so, but still hope there is a way to find this info.